# Swapping the administrative rights of two active users

Tags: administration, profile, licenses

I have two active users: Akira the administrator, and Naoki the non-administrator.

I want to transfer the admin rights of Akira to Naoki. However, according to this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006508&language=en_US&type=1), I need to deactivate/freeze the account of the previous administrator (i.e Akira). I do not want to do that as both of them are still within the organization, and both of them have reports and dashboards related to them. I am concerned that deactivating/freezing might cause errors.

Is there any way to do a simple swap of the user roles/privileges/rights?

Another concern I have is that the two users are currently on different licenses. I am unable to edit their license types. Is this behavior correct?

Comment: maybe you can swap emails and usernames  for that users?

Comment: Can you share license types for the respective users?

Comment: Can't you just update the profile of user directly?

Comment: The point of the documentation is, you can't have zero System Administrators. So if SA#1 left the company you can't deactivate them until someone else has become System Administrator. If you're not trying to deactivate anyone the article isn't relevant.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. One of them has license type Salesforce, the other has Salesforce Platform.

Answer (score 2):

The [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006508&language=en_US&type=1) about this says:

> deactivate or freeze the previous System Administrator's login (if
>   they're no longer with your company).

Obviously other admin is still in your company. So first change Naoki the non-administrator to System Administrator profile. After this, change Akira the administrator to non-admin profile.

I can't comment on licence types as you didn't share their license types.

Comment: A link to that documentation would improve the answer quality.